# XML: получение префикса для XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Есть XML (покажу интересующую его часть):

```
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gost28147" />
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:transport-gost2001" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>
```

Создаю XmlNamespaceManager и через XPathNavigator пробегаюсь по узлам и собираю XmlNamespaceScope.ExcludeXml. Но вот в чем проблема... нет префикса для добавления в XmlNamespaceManager. Либо префикс определяется как "xml", а на самом деле если указывать его у узла, то он будет "ds". В итоге потом не работает поиск по XPath.

**Как можно определить из такого XML правильные префиксы для узлов и URI для них, чтобы заполнить XmlNamespaceManager ?**

Comment: Возможно полезно будет добавить код, того что Вы делаете :)

Comment: Хмм... В данном xml префиксов нет. Но в любом случае их можно задавать _любые_. Главное, чтобы префикс был привязон к правильному пространству имён.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, создаю шифрованное сообщение через EcryptedData в C#. На выходе получается такая вот конструкция без указанных неймспейсов в "явную".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а это как есть какое-то выражение "видишь суслика ? а он есть"..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В приведённом куске xml используются *пространства имён по умолчанию* (default namespace). Это значит, что у них нет префиксов.

Запись без префиксов, что неудивительно, уменьшает размер xml. Но их придётся использовать, если в одном узле используются более одного пространства имён.

Чтобы в коде получить нужные данные с помощью XPath мы, тем не менее, должны задавать префиксы.

```
var document = new XPathDocument("test.xml");
var navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);

manager.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#");
manager.AddNamespace("b", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

var node = navigator.SelectSingleNode(
    "a:EncryptedData/b:KeyInfo/a:EncryptedKey/b:KeyInfo/b:X509Data/b:X509Certificate",
    manager);
```

В данном примере мы получаем самый последний из показанных в вопросе узлов, последовательно указывая цепочку элементов.

`EncryptedData` и `EncryptedKey` имеют одинаковое пространство имён. Добавляем его в менеджер, задавая префикс `a` (можно использовать любой, скажем, `foo` или `enc`).

Элементы `KeyInfo` расположены в другом пространстве имён. Тоже добавляем его в менеджер, задавая префикс `b`.

Теперь самое интересное. Элементы `X509Data` и `X509Certificate`, на первый взгляд, не имеют неймспейсов. Однако, они вложены в элемент с пространством имён по умолчанию (без префикса) и, так как они сами не имеют префикса, значит сами относятся к этому же пространству имён. Следовательно в XPath мы тоже должны указать для них тот же префикс `b`, привязанный к нужному неймспейсу.

---

Дополню.

Эти элементы:

```
<node xmlns="example.org"/>

<foo:node xmlns:foo="example.org"/>
```

согласно спецификации xml *одинаковы*. Потому что имеют одинаковые имена и определены в одном и том же пространстве имён. Префикс не имеет никакой роли.

Comment: 9К ровно! Поздравляю!

Comment: Спасибо за отличный ответ.

Comment: Просто все дело в том, что код: manager.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#");
формируется автоматически при анализе документа и получается что префикс могу указать любой сгенерированный. Но вот сам запрос к XML "navigator.SelectSingleNode......" указывается вручную в настройках. И получается что документ может быть с префиксами, может быть без префиксов и т.п.. Ну в общем понятно, что толково это не автоматизировать с первого взгляда.